# Error 1241 in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to make an sql query to subtract two values from different table to determine the remaining balance of each client. here's my sql query. but i get an error 1241 (operand should contain 1 column(s)). i already put an alias, "BALANCE".

```
SELECT tblClientInfo.ClientID, 
  (SELECT tblLoanPayment.ClientID,  
     SUM(tblLoanPayment.AmountPaid) FROM tblLoanPayment) -
  (SELECT tblLedger.ClientID,  tblLedger.LoanAmount from tblLedger) AS BALANCE
FROM tblClientInfo, tblLedger, tblLoanPayment 
WHERE tblClientInfo.ClientID = 1
```

Can you help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: Also: you should define **JOIN conditions** between all those tables! Otherwise you end up with a cartesian product of all rows from one table with all rows from the second (and the third table) - way too many rows....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seleting two columns!

```
(Select tblLoanPayment.ClientID,  sum(tblLoanPayment.AmountPaid)
```

You must select **one column only** to use math operators!

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT SUM(t.AmountPaid)
   FROM tblLoanPayment t
   WHERE t.ClientID = 1) -
  (SELECT t.LoanAmount 
   from tblLedger
   WHERE t.ClientID = 1)
FROM dual;
```

Comment: can i ask another thing? i am putting the answer to this query in a column in my jtable, what would be the column name?>

Comment: @zairahCS. You will need to give it an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Your second subselect is giving two columns and `-` only operates on single values.

Your subselects may also give strange results if no payments have been made; I find the query easier to read if you just rewrite it as a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT ci.ClientID, ledger.LoanAmount - COALESCE(SUM(AmountPaid), 0) Remaining
FROM tblClientInfo ci 
JOIN tblLedger ledger ON ci.ClientID=ledger.ClientId 
LEFT JOIN tblLoanPayment lp ON ci.ClientID=lp.ClientId
GROUP BY ci.ClientID, ledger.loanAmount
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08d1f/4).